# Trying to scrape text from forebets.com

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape certain information from forebet.com. I seem to be able to scrape the hometeam,awayteam,location but not the predicted score,correct score or weather.

Can somebody please look at my code and tell me home to scrape the predicted score, correct score and weather.
This is my code so far:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.forebet.com/en/predictions-world/world-cup').text


soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
teams= soup.find_all('a', class_= 'tnmscn')
for team in teams:
    hometeam = team.find('span',class_= 'homeTeam').text

    predictedscore = team.select_one('div', class_='ex_sc tabonly')
    awayteam = team.find('span',class_ = 'awayTeam').text
    date = team.find('span', class_='date_bah').text
    location = team.find('name address', 'content').text
    weather = team.find('span', class_="wnums")[0].text
    print(hometeam,predictedscore ,awayteam,date,weather)
```

Thank you for the help

Try to scrape forebet.com can't seem to scrape all the necessary data.

Answer (score 0):

You're looping through hyperlinks with `tnmscn` class, but that [covers only teams and date info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuxBr.png); if you also want more data like location/weather/scores/odds/etc., you need to [cover the whole row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAsyr.png)

```py
# teams = soup.find_all('a', class_= 'tnmscn')
rows = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'rcnt'})
# for team in teams:
for r in rows:
    hometeam = r.find('span',class_= 'homeTeam').text
    #### AND SO ON ####
```

<sub>(You can also loop with `for team in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'rcnt'})` and continue using `team.find...` inside the loop - it won't make a difference in terms of results, but I thought `for r in rows...` makes better sense [in terms of readability] now that it's looping over whole rows [instead of just the home/away teams column].)</sub>

---

About getting the location with this line:

> ```py
>     location = team.find('name address', 'content').text
> ```

I get an [AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8949252/6146136) on this line because **`.find('name address', 'content')`** returns `None` [and you can't get `.text` from `None`]. I'd be rather surprised if you don't also get such an error, because the main input to [`.find`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) is expected to be a [tag name](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#id12) and trying to find `name address` would never return anything as html tag names don't have spaces in them.

---

And about getting the predicted score with this line:

> ```py
>     predictedscore = team.select_one('div', class_='ex_sc tabonly')
> ```

`class_` is not an argument you can pass to [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors)/`.select_one`, so it'll just be selecting the first `div` inside `team`. You can pass more elaborate [CSS selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) so it should have been like **`.select_one('div.ex_sc.tabonly')`**.

What *should* be used instead is **`.find('span', {'itemprop': 'location'}).meta['content']`** to get the `content` attribute of `meta` tags [such as this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIcfx.png).

Also, please not that this actually [gets you the **correct score**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0i590.png) rather than the *predicted* score.

---

> to scrape the predicted score, correct score and weather

If you're looping over the whole row, then you can use

- **`.find('span', class_='forepr').text`** to get predicted score
- **`.find('div', class_='ex_sc tabonly').text`** to get correct score
- **`.find('div', class_="prwth tabonly")`** to get weather, but it may be missing, so you should

  - have *`if weather: weather = weather.text`* in another line to avoid getting AttributeError
  - [and add another line with *`else: continue`* if you want to skip such "rows"]

---

---

##### Suggested Solution:

Even though it's only really an issue for the weather data here, it's always safer to check where `.find...` or `.select...` returned anything before trying to get `.text`; and since you're doing this [`.find....text`] repeatedly, it's more convenient to just have it as a function.

I already [a function for this](https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u) that I often use when scraping with bs4, but it uses `.select_one` (not `.find`). All you need is a list of selectors and you can get all the data in one statement if you use [list comprehension](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp):

```py
# def selectForList.... # PASTE FROM https://pastebin.com/ZnZ7xM6u

rData = [selectForList(r, [
  'span.homeTeam', 'span.awayTeam', # home/away teams
  'span.forepr', 'div.ex_sc.tabonly', # pred/correct scores
  'span.date_bah', # date [location below]
  ('span[itemprop="location"]>meta[itemprop="name address"][content]', 'content'), 
  'div.prwth.tabonly>span.wnums', # temperature
]) for r in soup.select('div.rcnt')]
```

You could just print [by setting the print option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcSAM.png) of `selectForList` with `printList=' '`, or you could loop through `rData` to have more control over how it's printed.

```py
for r in rData: 
    print(f'# {r[0]} vs {r[1]}: {r[3] if r[3] else "score_unknown"}', 
          f'[pred: {r[2]}] on {r[4]} (at {r[5]})', 
          f'[{("temp: "+r[6]) if r[6] else "no_weather_data"}]')
    
### PRINTED OUTPUT BELOW ###

# Argentina vs France: 2 - 2 [pred: X] on 18/12/2022 16:00 (at Lusail Iconic Stadium) [temp: 21°]
# Croatia vs Morocco: 0 - 0 [pred: X] on 17/12/2022 16:00 (at Khalifa International Stadium) [temp: 22°]
# Argentina vs Croatia: 1 - 1 [pred: X] on 13/12/2022 20:00 (at Lusail Iconic Stadium) [temp: 22°]
# France vs Morocco: 3 - 1 [pred: 1] on 14/12/2022 20:00 (at Al Bayt Stadium) [temp: 22°]
# Juventus W vs Zurich (W): score_unknown [pred: 1] on 15/12/2022 18:45 (at Allianz Stadium) [no_weather_data]
# SL Benfica (W) vs Barcelona (W): score_unknown [pred: 2] on 15/12/2022 21:00 (at Caixa Futebol Campus) [no_weather_data]
```

---

For slightly more structured output, you could define [instead of a list] a reference dictionary (`selRef`) for the selectors and then get the data as list of dictionaries with the same keys as `selRef`:

```py
selRef = {'home_team': 'span.homeTeam', 'away_team': 'span.awayTeam', 'pred-y_n': ('div[class^="predict"]:has(>span.forepr)', 'class'), 'pred': 'span.forepr', 'correct_score': 'div.ex_sc.tabonly', 'date': 'span.date_bah', 'location': ('span[itemprop="location"]>meta[itemprop="name address"][content]', 'content'), 'temperature': 'div.prwth.tabonly>span.wnums', 'weather_icon': ('div.prwth.tabonly>img.wthc[src]', 'src')}

rdList = [dict(zip(
    selRef.keys(), selectForList(r, selRef.values()) #, printList=' ')
)) for r in soup.select('div.rcnt')]
```

then you could use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) to covert it to DataFrame as simply as **`pandas.DataFrame(rdList)`**. [ [View DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkZE8.png) ]

---

You might notice that in addition to splitting up the predictions, I've also added a `weather_icon` column. This column can be used to add in a descriptions of the weather

```py
wiRef = {'w-32': 'sunny', 'w-31': 'clear', 'w-30':'cloudy-day', 'w-29':'cloudy-night', 'w-20': 'fog', 'w-12': 'rainy-day', 'w-11': 'rainy-night'}

for ri, w in ([(i, r['weather_icon']) for i, r in enumerate(rdList) if r['weather_icon']]):
    rdList[ri]['weather_icon'] = f'https://www.forebet.com{w}' # replace with full link
    w = w.split('/')[-1].split('.png')[0].strip()
    rdList[ri]['weather'] = wiRef[w] if w in wiRef else f'{w}.png'

# import pandas
pandas.DataFrame(rdList).to_csv('wcPreds.csv', index=False)
```

The full list of weather icons as well the contents of the output 'wcPreds.csv' can be found in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bQo1an4yS1tSOMDhmUTGYtUlgnHDQ47EmIcj4YyuIxo/edit?usp=sharing).

---

You can use **`print(pandas.DataFrame(rdList).drop(['weather_icon'], axis=1).rename({'temperature':'temp'}, axis=1).to_markdown(index=False))`** to print the markdown for table below:

| home_team | away_team | pred-y_n | pred | correct_score | date | location | temp | weather |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Argentina | France | predict | X | 2 - 2 | 18/12/2022 16:00 | Lusail Iconic Stadium | 21° | clear |
| Croatia | Morocco | predict | X | 0 - 0 | 17/12/2022 16:00 | Khalifa International Stadium | 22° | clear |
| Argentina | Croatia | predict_no | X | 1 - 1 | 13/12/2022 20:00 | Lusail Iconic Stadium | 22° | clear |
| France | Morocco | predict_y | 1 | 3 - 1 | 14/12/2022 20:00 | Al Bayt Stadium | 22° | clear |
| Juventus W | Zurich (W) | predict_y | 1 |  | 15/12/2022 18:45 | Allianz Stadium |  | nan |
| SL Benfica (W) | Barcelona (W) | predict_y | 2 |  | 15/12/2022 21:00 | Caixa Futebol Campus |  | nan |